# href value is being appended after the server name

Tags: javascript, anchor, href

I am specifying `Please visit <a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>` and the browser appends the server name in front e.g. `https://susref.congnos.com/www.yahoo.com`

Should I change my `href` to `<a href="https:\\www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>` will solve the issue?

Comment: Please show the code.. it's most likely in your code you are either not clearing a variable or you are adding or concating values without realizing it

Comment: Hi All. I am getting the following value from back end and putting it directly in html.                                    "ep.details": "To watch this program,  Please visit our <a target=\"_self\" href="www.yahoo.com/">full site</a>", I directly place this value in my html upon encountering it from back end. Please let me know if i need to specify more. THanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the scheme e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Please visit Yahoo</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">Please visit Yahoo</a>
```

Without the scheme (the http:// bit) the browser assumes the link is relative to your site

Answer (score 4):

Add `http://` on the front of the url in your href.

e.g. `<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Visit Yahoo</a>`